# Geth bsc node install problem

Tags: go-ethereum, nodes, geth-debugging, bsc

I'm trying to install a bsc fullnode, i'm following the bsc tutorial (https://docs.binance.org/smart-chain/developer/fullnode.html). But i ran into a problem.
At the last step when i launch the node it says :

> INFO [05-27|09:59:45.452] Starting Geth on Ethereum mainnet...
> Fatal: ./config.toml, line 35: field 'OracleThreshold' is not defined in gasprice.Config, see \https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/gasprice#Config for available fields

I saw this guy add similar problem... https://githubmemory.com/repo/binance-chain/bsc/issues/255

Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: where you able to figure this out? i've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now. feels like i'm going crazy

Comment: The original report was resolved https://github.com/binance-chain/bsc/issues/255. Did you try a fresh installation?

Answer (score 1):

You just need remove that line (line 35: OracleThreshold = 20).
Because go-ethereum was updated and the model of config is changed, you can see in https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/gasprice#Config -> the model don't have field "OracleThreshold"

Comment: Hello. This is very close to a "code only answer". Please add explanation to why this is supposed to work.